# I want to link several variables to one ID in stata

Tags: stata

I am new to Stata, and I am struggling with the following:

I have this table:

[image]

And I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Next time, please provide your data in a more user-friendly format e.g. using `dataex`. See the Stata tag for more information. It's difficult for users who want to help to copy data out of a screenshot image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that won't require merging the results onto the main dataset:

```
input id_household child mother
1781 1 0
1781 0 0
1781 0 0
1781 0 1
1784 0 1
1784 0 0 
1786 0 1
1786 0 0
1786 0 0
end

* if you want to add the flag to each row do these
egen mother_in_house = sum(mother), by(id_household) // Sums the number of mother flags in the house
egen children_in_houses = sum(child), by(id_household) // Sums the number of children flags
egen mother_with_child = max(children_in_houses & mother_in_house), by(id_household) // = 1 if both mother count and child count are > 0

* Afterwards if you only care about household ID and the mother_with_child flag
keep id_household mother_with_child
duplicates drop
```

I have a sense that your data expands further to the right than your screenshot, so solution may have to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: The `egen` function `sum()` went undocumented in Stata 9. It's the same `egen` function as that now called `total()` and not at all the same as the Stata function `sum()` (avoiding confusion was precisely why the name was changed in Stata 9).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution:

```
clear

input id_household child mother
1781 1 0
1781 0 0
1781 0 0
1781 0 1
1784 0 1
1784 0 0 
1786 0 1
1786 0 0
1786 0 0
end

bysort id_household: egen childcount = sum(child)
bysort id_household: egen mothercount = sum(mother)

contract id_household childcount mothercount

gen     mother_with_child = 0
replace mother_with_child = 1 if childcount >= 1 & mothercount >= 1

list id_household mother_with_child

     +---------------------+
     | id_hou~d   mother~d |
     |---------------------|
  1. |     1781          1 |
  2. |     1784          0 |
  3. |     1786          0 |
     +---------------------+
```

Note that this will destroy any other data you have in your original dataset (it's unclear from your example whether you have any). You may need to merge the results of my answer back into your original dataset.